# Database possibly compromised

Tags: magento-1.9, database, security

I want to know if strangers have accessed the database.

If so, I want to find out how they got access to the database.

I found a strange trigger in the database (screenshot below).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your site contains a skimmer disguised as `googletagmanager.eu`. Attackers managed to inject this skimmer in over 270 stores this week, and - sadly - also yours.

In the cases that I investigated, attackers used a flaw in MySQL/adminer to gain access to the victim sites. Because you shared an adminer screenshot, I suspect they used the same method on your store.

You should thoroughly scrutinize your site for hidden backdoors, disguised admin accounts and such. My [eCommmerce anti-virus](https://sansec.io) may help. See also:

https://gwillem.gitlab.io/2019/01/17/adminer-4.6.2-file-disclosure-vulnerability/

https://twitter.com/gwillem/status/1098926474571235329

Comment: Thanks for writing. I would like to take your offer to help.

Comment: Email me at gwillem@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

@Jam: Your site is definitely infected. You can see the more details on below URL from Willem.

https://gwillem.gitlab.io/2017/02/14/triggered-malware/

You can see more details on the the exact issue you have on his website.